# How to get TextInput Value with useRef?

Tags: react-native

I try to get value of TextInput with

> useRef

but it gives undefined. This is my code:

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
 <TextInput
     ref={inputRef}
     value={'test'}
     editable={false}
     style={styles.InputStyle}
 />
console.log(inputRef.current.value)  --->   gives undefined
```

Comment: Try this `inputRef.current.state.value`.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'inputRef.current.state.value')  it gives this error @maltoze

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access TextInput's Value you better use state for that https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html
as following function component:

```
  const [inputValue,setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  //Getting state value
  console.log(inputValue);
  return (
   //Setting state Value using setInputValue
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Test" onChangeText={(value)=>setInputValue(value)}/>
    </View>
  )
```

stateful component example:

```
 state = {
        inputValue: '',
    };

render(){
  //Using state value
  console.log(this.state.inputValue);
  return (
  //Setting state value
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Test" onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({inputValue: value})}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

if you want to use ref to the input you should use useRef Hook:

```
export default function App() {
  const refForInput = useRef(null);

  const printValueOfInputUsingRef = () => {
    //to get the value u from a ref you should access it via 
    //ref.current.value object
    console.log(refForInput.current.value);
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={refForInput} value={'Some Value'}/>
      <Button onPress={handleOnPress}>Show The Value</Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
 <TextInput
     ref={inputRef}
     value={'test'}
     editable={false}
     style={styles.InputStyle}
     // Add These lines
     onChangeText={value => {
            // can be called anywhere to set value
            inputRef.current.value = value
          }}
 
 />



console.log(inputRef.current.value)  --->  now gives textinput value
```

Answer (score -3):

set the reference using a function Like this:

```
<TextInput ref={(ref) => { this.inputRef= ref; }} />
```

Then you can access to the reference with `this.inputRef`